# Occasionally Segmentation Fault with iterators

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, iterator, segmentation-fault

I'm currently working on a projekt about an application which is able to create a playable game level out of a drawn image (can be found here: [Github](https://github.com/offset/draw-it)). To do so, I'm using openCV for image processing.
My problem is a function which is supposed to draw the detected lines (which are the 'walls' in the level) to an image.

```
void LineFinder::drawDetectedLines( cv::Scalar color)
{
    for (auto it = Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines().begin(); it != Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines().end(); ++it)
    {
        // The lines are stored in an std::vector<cv::Vec4i>, 
        // so basically in a vector which contains vectors with 4 elements each
        cv::Point pt1((*it)[0], (*it)[1]);
        cv::Point pt2((*it)[2], (*it)[3]);

        // draws a line from pt1 to pt2
        cv::line(Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getImage(), pt1, pt2, color);

        ++it;
    }
}
```

When this function executes, most times I get a segmentation fault, but sometimes it works and the result is as I expected. I do know that the vector contains elements.
So are there any possible causes for this behaivour you can think of?

EDIT: Interestingly, when the function which uses this function already successfully executed once, I can reexecute it again and again and no error occurs.

EDIT2: I still don't know why I get the segmentation fault with the iterators, but without them it somehow works:

```
void LineFinder::drawDetectedLines( cv::Scalar color)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines().size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::Point pt1(Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines()[i][0], Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines()[i][1]);
        cv::Point pt2(Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines()[i][2], Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines()[i][3]);

        cv::line(Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getImage(), pt1, pt2, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to find the line/stack trace of the segfault?  Is it the same every time or does it change on every run?

Comment: Do you mean the line which causes the error?
It's the line with pt1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You increment the iterator twice. Once here:

```
for (auto it = Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines().begin(); it != Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines().end(); ++it)
```

and once here:

```
++it;
```

It might happen that you increment past the `end()` iterator, resulting in undefined behaviour.

Edit:

There is not enough information in your post to identify other problems, especially I don't know what all the variables and functions are. I also don't want to crawl through the whole git.

So here are some possible issues:

1. Is `Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines()` guaranteed to always return a reference to the same container?
2. Is the returned container guaranteed to not be modified while you iterate over it?
3. Are the objects stored in the container guaranteed to be arrays/vectors/... with at least 4 elements?

Edit2:

Well I had a short look at your repository, there is the error in linefinder.cpp:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> LineFinder::getLines()
{
    return lines;
}
```

`getLines()` does **not** return a reference to the same container, it returns a copy at each call. So you keep comparing the iterator of one container with the iterator of another one in your for-loop. Either change the definition to a reference return:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec4i>& LineFinder::getLines()
{
    return lines;
}
```

or save the return before you construct the iterators:

```
auto lines = Play::getInstance()->getFinder()->getLines();
for (auto it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); ++it)
{
```

Comment: Okay, but after deleting '++it;' there is still this weird behaviour. Btw., this line exists because there used to be a while loop which caused the same problem.

Comment: @BlackMamba I expanded my answer (again)